# Are most I/O operations asynchronous in the nature?

Tags: linux, io, operating-system, kernel

When I started to learn programming, all the I/O functions I've learned, such as read/fread, write/fwrite are all synchronous (blocking). Since then I've been curious about how asynchronous (non-blocking) I/O actually works.

Recently, I read some material on this topic and here is my understanding: in terms of I/O, what kernel actually does is to handle the ask from the application, and issue a request to the device controller. After that, it is free to do other things, for example, transfer control back to the application. When the device controller receives the request, it will perform the actual I/O operation on its own (e.g. Direct Memory Access), without consuming any CPU cycle. Once the operation is completed, device controller will notify kernel by a hardware interrupt (or similar form of signaling).

During this entire progress, the only part that actually consumes CPU cycles (e.g. blocking) is when kernel handles application's ask and issue request to corresponding device. So in this way, all common I/O operations should be asynchronous in the nature, right?

And for those synchronous I/O operations, we can easily build the synchronous versions based on the asynchronous versions. For example, after kernel issues the request to the device, instead of transferring the control back to the application, kernel can simply mark the application process as blocked for I/O and context switch to other processes. Only after kernel is notified of the completion of I/O operation, it can switch back to the previous process. This way, from the application's standpoint, the I/O operation is blocking, despite the fact that I/O is naturally non-blocking.

Please correct me if any of my understanding is wrong. Thanks for all your help

Comment: We don't do discussions on SO. Q&A only.

Comment: Got it but I think I already post my question in the foremost place of this post, the subject.

Comment: In the kernel it's all asynchronous. At the API level, there are various choices: blocking, non-blocking, or asynchronous.

Comment: @user207421 aren't asynchronous and non-blocking referring to the same thing?